# adding tplog writing ability to chained TP

Tags: kdb

I am trying to make Chained TP to write tplog file as well.

However, what i can see from the process log is l  every second.
refer to this link:https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/tick/chainedtick.q
in the shell script i already pointed out which tp to subscribe.

I changed these two functions:

```
if[system"t";
 .z.ts:{.u.pub'[.u.t;value each .u.t];@[`.;.u.t;@[;`sym;`g#]0#]}; 
  upd:{[t;x] t insert x;if[l;l enlist (`upd;t;x);j+:1];}]

if[not system"t";  
   upd:{[t;x] .u.pub[t;x];if[l;l enlist (`upd;t;x);i+:1];}]
```

also added

```
  .u.tick[src;.z.x 1];
```

at the end.

still trying to figure out why nothing in the tplog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.u.tick` (or `.u.l` which is defined in `.u.tick`) are not defined in chainedtp.q. `.u.tick` can be found in [tick.q](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick.q).

AquaQ Analytics' [TorQ](https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ) infrastructure has a chained TP process, which allows you to specify on startup whether you want a logfile to be created or not. More info can be found [here](https://aquaqanalytics.github.io/TorQ/Processes/#chained-tickerplant). (Full disclaimer, I’m an employee of AquaQ).

Comment: so i just added tick:{init[];if[not min(`time`sym~2#key flip value@)each t;'`timesym];@[;`sym;`g#]each t;d::.z.D;if[l::count y;L::`$":",y,"/",x,10#".";l::ld d]};  and will work?

Comment: `.u.ld` is used in that function as well so it may need to be defined. I think some of the what `.u.tick` is redundant EG applying `g# attribute since that's already being done.